# Fullcalendar callback ajax is not function

Tags: jquery, ajax, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use jquery Full Calendar from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar
But I have a problem when I implement Event Data:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But the calendar doesn't render anything. I checked in Firefox and Chrome console then them said "callback is not a function". What's this issues? And How can I return data?

Comment: So what is `callback`? `console.log(callback);`

Comment: What does your entire example look like, can you fiddle it? Also please include a sample of your xml feed.

Comment: I found it from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/ but I don't know how to use it. I run the example, but it doesn't work. Could you show me how it work?